# How to Keep Database and Server Connections active

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, connection

It seems like everyday I go to publish a service or connect to my SDE I get messages that I can't connect. It is particularly annoying when trying to publish a service to ArcServer. The connections are made, but for some reason they are timing out or becoming temporarily disconnected for whatever reason (Red X over the connection icons).

The fix is simple: As soon as I open Catalog and then double click on the connection, it re establishes connection and then I can do what I need in ArcMap. However, ideally I would like to stop this behavior.

Any ideas why this is happening? Can't find much in the help and it has been mentioned by several users in my organization.

Comment: Which version(s) of ArcGIS for Server and Desktop are you using?

Comment: 10.1 on both server and desktop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default behavior is to let connections remain active, so the
real issue is likely the feature in your environment which closes
open TCP/IP sessions:

- Firewall configuration
- Antivirus applications
- Network switch configuration
- Nightly database restarts
- Nightly application server restarts
- TCP-Keepalive timeout configuration
- "Sleep" mode on servers

Your organizational IT staff would have a better idea of what the
most likely cause is, and what the associated costs might be to
make changes.