# Failure to Access DBMS Server Error - ArcGIS/Postgres

Tags: postgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase

If connected to an SDE enabled Postgres database via ArcGIS (10.1) for a long period of time, maybe an hour +, I will often receive an error from ArcGIS stating "Failure to access the DBMS Server[my schema name.sde.GDB_items]. I can't pin down any specific event causing the error, and my fix is to simply restart ArcGIS. Disconnecting and re-connecting the database connection without an ArcGIS restart results in the same error message.

Its a minor inconvenience, but one that would save myself and others daily grief if corrected. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70185/how-to-keep-database-and-server-connections-active

Comment: That issue seems similar, but not the same. Double clicking or refreshing the connection won't solve the issue. Instead I need to fully close ArcMap and then re-open it. I don't think its a firewall or similar external issue, since the connections always remain active in QGIS or PGAdmin.

Comment: I have the same problem and the linked duplicate does not address this issue. did you ever find a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the sde.dbtune and make sure TCPKEEPALIVE is set to FALSE. If it is set to true, a slight network problem can kick off the connection in 10 minutes.

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/manager/geodatabase/administering_a-557706548/arcsde-1362237508.htm

The article is for 9.2, however the TCPKEEPALIVE parameter is still present in 10.2.2 dbtune