# ArcMap Desktop crashes when using geoprocessing tool with PostgreSQL layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, arcgis-10.4, serious-application-error

Whenever I use a geoprocessing tool (Clip tool) with a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table, the program crashes. If I make the process run in background, the process fails without any specific error message.

The input feature is a table located in the schema 'data' This is a very large table (~ 40 000 rows). The clip feature is a materialized view also from the schema 'data', but with a 'Definition Query' (ArcMap) applied to it so it returns only one polygon.

I looked at the PostgreSQL logs and everytime I use a geoprocessing tool, there is this error:

```
2017-02-08 22:43:13 EST LOG:  Could not reveive data from client : unrecognized winsock error 10054
```

The output location is in a scratch file geodatabase on the local computer.

The database connection is working fine. The permissions to write to PostgreSQL are OK (I connect with user 'postgres', which has superuser privilege).

If I run the equivalent process in QGIS (for exemple, Clip) with the exact same tables, everything works perfectly.

Software used:

Server-side:

- PostgreSQL 9.4.10 (64 bits)
- PostGIS 2.2.3
- Windows Server 2012 R2

Client-side:

- ArcMap 10.4
- Windows 10 (64 bits)
- PostgreSQL ODBC Driver version 9.05 (32 bits)

Comment: What happens when you do this in the foreground?  Does it give a Serious Application Error or something else?

Comment: Does the crash/failure happen immediately? Or does it occur after clip has been running for a while?

Comment: @PolyGeo: In the foreground, it does give a Serious Application Error.

Comment: @JayCummins: The crash happens after a few seconds (maybe 5 seconds) after the geoprocessing is launched.

Comment: Are you taking the opportunity to email Esri the details by clicking on that Serious Application Error dialog?  I suspect that until you can get it running in the foreground of ArcMap you are unlikely to be able to get it running in the background.

Comment: I work mainly with file geodatabases, but with PostgreSQL/PostGIS are you able to copy the "materialized view" polygon to be a feature class polygon, and test that in its place?

Comment: @PolyGeo: Yes I did send them an email (Send Error Report). Hummm I did not try to export one of those two tables to a ESRI feature class. But I did try to export another table from ArcGIS and it failed too with the error "each grid size must be at least three times larger tan the preceding grid size arcmap"

Comment: 10.5 has been released.  Are you in a position to install it, perhaps on another machine, to test whether it "just works" there?

Comment: Yes I am in position of installing 10.5. I am considering it

Comment: I suspect it may be caused by the antivirus running on the server. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981344/an-application-may-receive-the-10054-error-when-the-application-receives-data-from-a-connection-on-a-computer-that-is-running-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2-if-a-tdi-filter-driver-is-installed
Though I don't know why it doesn't happen with QGIS

Comment: Antivirus is #2 on the list! http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70185/how-to-keep-database-and-server-connections-active